# Dynamic pricing calculation where each unit becomes progressively less expensive than the one before it

Tags: php, algorithm, math

I'm trying to come up with an elegant way to do this and so far I have failed. The idea is simple enough:

Currently, I have a tiered pricing method.

- 1-10,000 @ $0.007
- 10,001-100,000 @ $0.005
- 100,001-1,000,000 @ $0.003
- 1,000,001+ @ $0.002

What I would like to do is have 1 at $0.007 and 1,000,000 at $0.002 where each one from 1 to 1,000,000 is progressively less expensive without having the hard stops at 10k, 100k, and 1m.

Every time I think I have it, I end up way off. This is what I have right now:

```
function getCost($units)
{
    $min            = 0.002;
    $max            = 0.007;
    $limit          = 1000000;
    
    if($units < $limit)
    {
        $pricePerUnit = (($limit - $units) / $limit * ($max - $min)) + $min;
    } else {
        $pricePerUnit = $min;
    }

    return $pricePerUnit * $units;
}
```

Things get cheaper as I get closer to the threshold this way, so there's this tipping point where I end up with a lower overall price the more units I add, and that's not what I want at all.

I know there's a very elegant way to do this, but I don't have it. What can I try next?

Comment: VtC because it's really not clear what you want here.

Comment: better to ask here http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach:

- The total price for 1 unit is $0.007.
- The total price for 1,000,000 units is $0.002 * 1,000,000 = $2,000.

In between, for N units, use for **the total price** a linear expression in `N`:

```
totalPrice = N * a + b.
```

At `N` units, the price per unit will be `pricePerUnit = totalPrice / N = a + b / N`.

We have the total price for 1 and 1,000,000 items:

```
        1 * a + b = $    0.007
1,000,000 * a + b = $2,000
```

Therefore we can find `a` and `b`:

```
a = $1,999.993 / 999,999 = $0.00199999499
b = $0.007 - a = $0.00500000501
```

So, for `N` units, the price per unit would be:

```
price = $0.00199999499 + ($0.00500000501 / N)
```

**EDIT**: as pointed in the comments by  @user3386109, decreasing with `1/N` is too fast. To fix such issues, one could use a slowly decreasing expression on `N` to represent the price per unit. One variant is something like `pricePerUnit = a + b / (1 + log N)`, with `a` and `b` suitably found such that we match the desired prices at 1 and 1,000,000.

This choice leads to

```
a +   1 * b = $0.007
a + 1/6 * b = $0.002
```

This implies that `pricePerUnit = $0.001 + $0.006 / (1 + log N)`.

Comment: I almost follow along with this. Where are you getting the $1,993?

Comment: ah - I still need to fix something, just a moment

Comment: I think it is fine now. The 1,999.993 is obtained by subtracting the first relation (the identity for 1 item) from the second (the identity for 1M items).

Comment: The problem with this is that the price per unit drops proportionally to `1/N`. So by the time you reach 10 units, the price is already down to $0.0025 per unit. In other words, the effective price per unit is $0.002 for any significant quantity.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure this is it.
Let's say I have 10 items. The first item is $10. If you buy two, I'll sell you the 2nd one for $9. The 3rd is $8, 4th for $7, 5th for $6 and the 6th one for $5. The 7th one and any beyond that still sell for $5 because that's the least I can sell it for to make money, but I still want to reward you for being a good customer. So if you buy all 10, you get all of them for $65, or an average price of $6.50 a piece.

Comment: @Greg-J Hm - I see, but if I interpret the example in the initial question through this comment, then the price per unit at 1,000,000 should not be $0.002 - because we would not be able to reward them later.  (in a similar way as the price per unit at 6 items in the sample above is not $5, but (10+9+..+5) / 6).

Comment: I believe you are looking for a strategy that at infinite quantity results in the minimum price. In this case it is possible to use N = infinity to find `a` and `b` in the last (below "edit") part of my answer. That would lead to a price per unit equal to `$0.002 + $0.005 / (1 + log N)`. (the logarithm is in base 10)

Answer (score 0):

With the example pricing you give, I think you're going to have "tipping points" if your goal is to re-price all units as the volume goes up.

For example

```
  500,000 @ $.0045 = $2,250 (.0045 is half way between .002 and .007)
1,000,000 @ $.002  = $2,000
```

Instead, if each unit has its own discounted price, I think the numbers work the way you want. The first unit costs .007 and additional units cost incrementally less, but the first unit always costs .007.

(This pricing matches the OPs comment "Let's say I have 10 items. The first item is $10. If you buy two, I'll sell you the 2nd one for $9. The 3rd is $8,..." and also the question title "each unit becomes progressively less expensive".)

I think you need to find the price of the first unit sold ($max) and the last unit sold and then take the average to find the price per unit.

For number of units less than the limit, the discount on the last unit sold is the number of units multipled by the incremental discount on each unit.

```
$min = .002;
$max = .007;
$limit = 1000000;

$priceDiff = $max - $min;
$discountPerUnit = $priceDiff / $limit;
$discount = ($units - 1) * $discountPerUnit;
$priceLast = $max - $discount;
$pricePerUnit = ($max + $priceLast) / 2;
```

If the number of units is more than the limit, you have the above for the first million (or whatever the limit is) plus .002 per each unit over the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best I can do

[image]

In C code:

```
double total_cost = pow( 6.57, log10(3.88 * N) ) / 96.7;
```

Below is a table of the total cost for various quantities. The second column is the expected total cost based on tiered pricing, and the last column is the total cost based on the formula.

```
      1    0.01    0.03
      3    0.02    0.08
     10    0.07    0.21
     30    0.21    0.51
    100    0.70    1.35
    300    2.10    3.32
   1000    7.00    8.89
   3000   21.00   21.82
  10000   50.00   58.38
  30000  150.00  143.32
 100000  300.00  383.54
 300000  900.00  941.64
1000000 2000.00 2519.85
3000000 6000.00 6186.60
```

It's a little on the high side, but what's wrong with a little extra profit :)